# Creating a scheduled task which uses a specific event log entry as a trigger

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to create a scheduled task which uses a Windows event log as a trigger. When an event is put into the event log, this task is kicked off. The event I want to monitor is event ID 8001, screenshot below.

I am using the .Net method in my script, as I couldn't find a way to do this with PowerShell natively. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This screenshot is a snapshot of an example Scheduled Task which targets the same event in which I want to monitor.

[image: Scheduled Task]

Here is my attempt so far.

```
$taskName = "MyRepetitiveTask"

$Service = new-object -ComObject ("Schedule.Service")
$Service.Connect()
$RootFolder = $Service.GetFolder("\")
$TaskDefinition = $Service.NewTask(0)
$TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = ''
$TaskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = $true
$TaskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $true
$Triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
$Trigger = $Triggers.Create(0) ## 0 is an event trigger
$Trigger.Enabled = $true
$TaskEndTime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(30);$Trigger.EndBoundary = $TaskEndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
$Trigger.Id = '8001'
$Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
$Action.Path = 'PowerShell.exe'
$action.Arguments = "$dropboxPath\request\Scripts\Hire\NetworkConnections\StartLTE-WiFi.ps1"
$RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($taskName, $TaskDefinition, 6, "System", $null, 5) | Out-Null
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you planning to use? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` It really depends on this to help answer the question the best way.

Comment: @ZachOlinske: You do not need any version check for this approach. Its a COM object approach and applicable for all version. 

MarcKean: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Marc: I have a script which does the same. You can refer it [Task Scheduler with PS](https://onejourneymultipletechnologies.blogspot.in/2016/10/scheduled-task-in-powershell.html)

Comment: @RanadipDutta I would use the the following PowerShell script to get the Event logs. Get-EventLogs. I will write some code for the answer.

Comment: This is the error I am getting: 

(8,8):Subscription:
At line:18 char:1
+ $RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($taskName, $TaskDefinition, 6, "Sy ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Answer (score 2):

Ok, done some other small modifications, but the main one which fixed this was adding the subscription line (5th last line).

```
### Variables
$dropboxDBfile = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? {$_.Name -eq 'host.db'}
$base64path = gc $dropboxDBfile.FullName | select -index 1
$dropboxPath = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64path)) # convert from base64 to ascii

$taskName = "Keep_WiFi_Connected"
$Path = 'PowerShell.exe'
$Arguments = "$dropboxPath\request\Scripts\Hire\NetworkConnections\StartLTE-WiFi.ps1"

$Service = new-object -ComObject ("Schedule.Service")
$Service.Connect()
$RootFolder = $Service.GetFolder("\")
$TaskDefinition = $Service.NewTask(0) # TaskDefinition object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382542(v=vs.85).aspx
$TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = ''
$TaskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = $True
$TaskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $True
$TaskDefinition.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = $False
$Triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
$Trigger = $Triggers.Create(0) ## 0 is an event trigger https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383898(v=vs.85).aspx
$Trigger.Enabled = $true
$TaskEndTime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(30);$Trigger.EndBoundary = $TaskEndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
$Trigger.Id = '8003' # 8003 is for disconnections and 8001 is for connections
$Trigger.Subscription = "<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational'><Select Path='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational'>*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig'] and EventID=8003]]</Select></Query></QueryList>"
$Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
$Action.Path = $Path
$action.Arguments = $Arguments
$RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($taskName, $TaskDefinition, 6, "System", $null, 5) | Out-Null
```

Works perfectly - remember to **run as admin** when running this PowerShell script.

Comment: I can confirm this works for me for USB unplug event (2102), but I need to add that I spent an hour trying to test this with starting notepad.exe, and task failed to start with message `The operator or administrator has refused the request (0x800710E0)`. Once I changed action to powershell with arguments it worked. This was on RedStone 5. I don't understand why, and I really wasn't expecting  that notepad fails to run while powershell works!

Answer (score 1):

I did some googling and found a nice way to do this:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction  -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command $Command"

$CIMTriggerClass = Get-CimClass -ClassName MSFT_TaskEventTrigger -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler:MSFT_TaskEventTrigger
$Trigger = New-CimInstance -CimClass $CIMTriggerClass -ClientOnly
$Trigger.Subscription = 
@"
<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="System"><Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog'] and EventID=6005]]</Select></Query></QueryList>
"@
$Trigger.Enabled = $True 

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -TaskName "  Startup"  -Description 'test' -User 'System' -Force
```